# AndroidStudio 3.5 - ClassNotFoundException - View referenced from other module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.5

The project is a multi-module project that contains a `mediaplayer` module with a custom view `MediaCustomView` inside.
The module `app` depends on `mediaplayer`.

Context: In the `app` module...

Using AS 3.5 with `android-gradle-plugin:3.5.0-beta02` makes the app crash at runtime when the `LayoutInflater` tries to inflate an xml using `MediaCustomView`

Using AS 3.5 with `android-gradle-plugin:3.4.1` works just fine.

I remember reading about this somewhere but I can't find it anymore. Anybody knows what's happening and how I can fix it and still use `android-gradle-plugin:3.5.0-beta02` ?

Comment: Not a solution, but you should generally avoid using `+` for versions anywhere.

Comment: I'm not using `+` anymore :D , was just for the ease of writing the question. Will edit it out.

Comment: Why removing the `android-studio-3.5` tag? This happens only on AS 3.5...

Comment: can yoy pass your dependencies code?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `File` menu and `Invalidate Cashes/Restart`, with this option you able to clear your all previous (unused) dependency and cashes.

I hope that will work for you.

Comment: Have you try to change the latest version of inside your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

Comment: Yes, using 5.4.1

Comment: I just created a new project with `Android Studio 3.5 Beta 3` with Gradle `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-beta03'` and inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` file i used `gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`. that working without any error. I didn't understand what went wrong with you.

Comment: Did you add a new android module inside this project with a custom view inside it?

Comment: so project should have 2 modules: `app` and `myandroidmodule` or whatever name. In `app/build.gradle` under `dependencies` have `implementation project(":myandroidmodule")`.
Now in `myandroidmodule/src/<your package>` create a custom view for instance `MySpecialImageView: ImageView` then use `MySpecialImageView` in a layout xml inside the `app` module and run the app. App crashes for me with agp `3.5.0-beta03`. Works fine with `3.4.1`. As described in the question.

Comment: No, I just created a new plain project to check it out, otherwise, I used a stable version for all our product app, do one thing create a new project and play with it like i did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194431/discussion-between-andrei-verdes-and-mehul-solanki).